# Check what a subquery returned

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO cpus (
    `friendlyname`, `group
) VALUES (
    'something', (SELECT `key` FROM `groups` WHERE `key` = 'something')
);
```

However, I want to get the result of the subquery. Initially I thought it would be something like

```
SELECT `key` FROM `groups` WHERE `key` = 'something' AS `result`
```

but that didn't work. What else should I try?

Comment: `SELECT `key` FROM `groups` WHERE `key` = 'something' ` This should works, but why you need subquery results?

Comment: I want to see if it returns anything or not. The 'something' would be user-input.

Comment: `INSERT` statement doesn't return result set. If you want to know if subquery return data then you should check before `INSERT` statement.

Comment: So is there no way to do it without two queries?

Comment: If subquery return `null` you can set the value with `ifnull` function.

Comment: Actually, you don't need subquery. Because `SELECT key FROM groups WHERE key = 'something'` always return 'something' which 'something' is user-input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MYSQL IF to check if it returns anything or not

Try out this:

```
INSERT INTO cpus
(
`friendlyname`, 
 `group
) 
VALUES 
(
  'something', 
  IF((SELECT `key` FROM `groups` WHERE `key` = 'something') is null,'Do  something on success','Else' )
);
```

Follow the link below for more details on MYSQL control flow:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html